# Why does SO say I earned the yearling badge 4 times in recent achievements? all of them link to the same thing

Tags: bug

When I look at awards (in meta) it says I have two yearling badges.  That seems about right.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/121332?tab=badges&sort=recent

Did I earn 4 just now? unlikely that I started playing with 4 SE sites at the same time.  2, perhaps (SO and MSO).  Most likely, just one - SO.

picture:

[image]

html, in case it's useful

```
<div class="js-date-group date-group">
        <div class="date-group-toggle-row js-date-group-toggle">
            <span class="date-header">Yesterday</span>

        <span class="single-rep-site-container" title="You earned 20 reputation yesterday on Stack Overflow">
                <span class="js-faux-column rep-change js-rep-change rep-up" title="">
    +20
</span>

        </span>
<a class="date-group-toggle"></a>
        </div>

        <ul class="js-items items">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/121332?tab=badges&amp;sort=recent" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track=" achievements_popup.click({ item_type:2 })">
                        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-stackoverflowmeta" title="Meta Stack Overflow"></div>
<span class="js-faux-column rep-change " title="" style="width: 24px;">

</span>
                        <div class="message-text">
                            <h4>You've earned the "Yearling" badge. See your profile.</h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/121332?tab=badges&amp;sort=recent" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track=" achievements_popup.click({ item_type:2 })">
                        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-stackoverflowmeta" title="Meta Stack Overflow"></div>
<span class="js-faux-column rep-change " title="" style="width: 24px;">

</span>
                        <div class="message-text">
                            <h4>You've earned the "Yearling" badge. See your profile.</h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/121332?tab=badges&amp;sort=recent" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track=" achievements_popup.click({ item_type:2 })">
                        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-stackoverflowmeta" title="Meta Stack Overflow"></div>
<span class="js-faux-column rep-change " title="" style="width: 24px;">

</span>
                        <div class="message-text">
                            <h4>You've earned the "Yearling" badge. See your profile.</h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/121332?tab=badges&amp;sort=recent" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track=" achievements_popup.click({ item_type:2 })">
                        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-stackoverflowmeta" title="Meta Stack Overflow"></div>
<span class="js-faux-column rep-change " title="" style="width: 24px;">

</span>
                        <div class="message-text">
                            <h4>You've earned the "Yearling" badge. See your profile.</h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370495/subsetting-in-r/23370625#23370625" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site.switch({ target_site:1, item_type:6 }); achievements_popup.click({ item_type:1 })">
                        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-stackoverflow" title="Stack Overflow"></div>
<span class="js-faux-column rep-change js-rep-change rep-up" title="13 hours ago" style="width: 24px;">
    +10
</span>
                        <div class="message-text">
                            <h4>Subsetting in R</h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041993/how-to-rename-a-git-project-name/2042020#2042020" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track="site.switch({ target_site:1, item_type:6 }); achievements_popup.click({ item_type:1 })">
                        <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-stackoverflow" title="Stack Overflow"></div>
<span class="js-faux-column rep-change js-rep-change rep-up" title="16 hours ago" style="width: 24px;">
    +10
</span>
                        <div class="message-text">
                            <h4>How to rename a git project name?</h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is still part of the recent [MSO/MSE split](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/) as it is clear the four years that you've been active on MSO has been reflected [almost instantaneously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=121332):

[image]

Note that this badge can be awarded multiple times.

Comment: I realize it can be awarded multiple times, but why has it been awarded multiple times NOW?  (rather than gradually, say (for example) every year)?

Comment: @AlexBrown: The MSO/MSE split stripped a host of badges from people who formerly had it on MSO, as things were migrated to MSE. As such, retro-active awarding of badges have occurred for badge-worthy participation on the "new MSO". It may have just been sluggish as it's catching up to everyone.

Comment: oh.  it could have said.  I wondered if SO had a bug, happy to see it's now perfect again (said without irony)